# Reference to generic type 'Resource' requires arguments in <…>

Tags: ios, swift

I have a struct as below which is confirming a protocol as below

```
struct ResourceItems<T: Decodable>: MyProtocol {
} 



protocol MyProtocol: Decodable {

}
```

Now I am creating another protocol & want to access ‘ResourceItems’ in that protocol as below

```
protocol  ObjectConverterProtocol{
    var response : ResourceItems {get set}
}
```

But getting the error as ‘

> Reference to generic type 'ResourceItems' requires arguments in <…>

’

Please guide me what I have to pass as a generic parameter.  I tried with AnyObject & Any but both of them does not confirm Codable.

I can’t get how to fix this issue. Please guide.

Comment: You should set `Resource<Type>` in protocol

Answer (score 3):

Since ResourceItems is a generic type you need to use it like that also in your protocol. For this you can use an associated type

```
protocol  ObjectConverterProtocol{
    associatedtype ResourceType: Decodable
    var response : ResourceItems<ResourceType> {get set}
}
```

and then you can use your protocol

```
struct Converter: ObjectConverterProtocol {
    typealias ResourceType = String

    var response: ResourceItems<ResourceType>
    //or var response: ResourceItems<String>
}
```

or even make `Converter` generic

```
struct Converter<C: Decodable>: ObjectConverterProtocol {
    typealias ResourceType = C

    var response: ResourceItems<ResourceType>
}

let converter = Converter(response: ResourceItems<String>())
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `ResourceItems` is a ***generic type***, you need to specify the type of *generic parameter* explicitly.

Now, since the *generic parameter* must be `Decodable`, you must define the `Decodable` type with `ResourceItems` in *angular brackets `<...>`*.

Let's assume, struct `DecodableObject` is of a `Decodable` type, i.e.

```
struct DecodableObject: Decodable {
    //....
}
```

So, you can now define `response` of type `ResourceItems` like so,

```
protocol ObjectConverterProtocol {
    var response : ResourceItems<DecodableObject> {get set}
}
```